# How can I conveniently dump a backpack or bag of holding?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-direwolf20

After completing some odd quests to get a special sword, I found myself loving bags of all varieties. Sometimes, I just get the urge to put on some pink leather armor, and prance around while I fill up my little golden bags of holding with as many pretty flowers as I can find.

The trouble is, emptying these portable inventories is a bit of a chore when you carry a few or more. Primarily, I use an Ender pouch linked to a chest that dumps into my AE system to empty out my inventory while adventuring, but I don't like sending back a bunch of things that are just going to occupy types needlessly on my drives. Hence, I fill up my beautiful little bags, and spend close to half an hour emptying them when I finally return.

There's no way that I can find to hook these up to any kind of conduit or interface to make emptying them into sorting chests automatic. I want to put my bags and backpacks in something, then get back empty bags. What can I use to do this? I'm currently playing the Direwolf20 1.7.10 pack, but I'm up for anything that works, in-pack or not.

I know I could use portable cells from AE2, but:

- Same problem with lots of different types (there's over 100 types of seeds)
- Expensive to make, and you have to charge them, so it's easier to carry a bunch of bags or backpacks
- They ... just aren't ... *pretty* enough.

Comment: Just... link take a second ender pouch with you that is linked to your... pretty... chests (or other prefered storage solution for pretty things)?

Comment: consider adding OpenBlocks luggage to the list. Although it might work differently since it's an entity.

Comment: I've never heard of anything in any mod that empties bags for you, but I have to ask, how is opening a bag and shift-clicking everything taking you a half-hour? It's incredibly easy to setup automatic export buses, or even prioritized storage buses, to sort your stuff for you and EXPEL it from your ME network into it's proper chest\barrel...

Comment: @Ender OCD (and a buggy sorting system that eventually works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ender pouch and instead of dumping the items into your ae system, dump them into a sorting system. You may consider using filing cabinets instead of chests because it can store any item with the same item id aka ignoring metadata and nbt. And for quick access you can hook up storage buses to the filing cabinets

Answer (score 0):

With Forestry Backpacks you can shift right-click the bag onto a chest or a Storage Drawer controller and it will empty what the storage will accept.

Answer (score -1):

You must have a horrendous amount of portable storage if it takes you half of an hour to empty it. The best I can say to do is set up a sorting system with pipes or ducts (if you have them) use enderpouches. I hope that I helped in some way. Have good luck.